# Show that all irreducible polynomials divide $t^{p^d-1} -1$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

I have shown that if $f$ is irreducible with $deg(f) = d$ then $\mathbb{F}_p [t] / \langle f\rangle$ is a field with $p^d$ elements. I've also shown that $\langle f\rangle$ is precisely those polynomials $g$ where $g(\alpha) = 0$ where $\alpha$ is the image of $t$ in the quotient map.

Now I need to show that this implies $f$ divides $t^{p^d-1}-1$. I have worked out some facts but I'm having trouble putting them together:

- $t^{p^d} - t$ is the zero polynomial as it is zero on every element of the field.
- I want to some how show that then this polynomial is 0 and so it is in the ideal generated by $\langle f\rangle$ and then some how use the fact $\langle f\rangle$ is maximal to see that $f$ then divides it.

Thanks.

Comment: $t^{p^d-1}$ or $t^{p^{d-1}}$?

Comment: The first one, I was having trouble writing it as you can see

Comment: You can achieve more than one symbol in the superscript by putting the symbols you need into {} brackets. I will edit your question to be readable.

Comment: Okay thank you, I also wanted to write $F_p$ is a blackboard bold $F$ is that possible? If so how is that done? Thanks

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{F}$? Write \mathbb{F}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the element $[t]\in\mathbb{F}_p[t]/<f>.$ Since the multiplicative group of non-zero elements in $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/<f>$ has $p^{d}-1$ elements and contains $[t]$, we know that $[t]^{p^d-1}=1$. This means precisely that $[t^{p^d-1}-1]=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/<f>,$ meaning that $f$ divides $t^{p^d-1}-1$.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't $\mathbb{F}_p[t] / <f>$ have $p^d$ elements? Also how do we know that $[t]^{p^d-1} = 1$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/<f>$ has $p^d$ elements, and therefore $p^d-1$ non-zero elements. These non-zero elements form a group under the field multiplication. Also, if you have any finite group $G$ of order $n$, then $g^n=e$ for all $g\in G$. To see this, take the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$, and note that its order divides $n$ by Langrange's Theorem.

Comment: Also doesn't this then mean that $t^{p^d-1}-1 \in <f>$ and so $t^{p^d-1} - 1 = h(t)f(t)$ for some $h \in \mathbb{F}_p[t]$ which says that $t^{p^d-1}$ divides $f$? Thanks again

Comment: The statement $t^{p^d-1}-1\in<f>$ means that $f$ divides $t^{p^d-1}-1$

Comment: Oh okay, I was thinking that meant that $t^{p^d-1}-1$ divides $<f>$. Thanks

Comment: Have I completely answered your question?